# New linux user account can't access ROS tooling

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I installed ROS on my PC using my normal user account. I can use all ROS tooling such as catkin_make or roslaunch on this account.

I just created a new user using 'adduser, however this user can't access any of the ROS tooling.

I added the /opt/ros/indigo/bin path to the user's PATH, which helps the user locate the executeables but they still fail when running. It feels like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with adding this new user, am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257258/new-linux-user-account-can%27t-access-ros-tooling/) by [Jazula](https://answers.ros.org/users/29729/jazula/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you `source`-ing `/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` for the new user?

You might have added it to the `.bashrc` of your other user and then forgot about it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jazula](https://answers.ros.org/users/29729/jazula/) on 2017-03-20**:
That fixed everything. Thank you